# Run static website using node or grunt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I am new to node or grunt. I have developed a website using html, css and bootstrap. Now I am confused how to run this site? shall I use nodejs to serve static files or use grunt?

Most of the examples I see use `grunt-watch` and `grunt-serve` to serve files. Is watching a file necessary only during development phase and not in production right?

I would also like to minify the files(css,js etc) before I host it. I am from java background where I normally use apache tomcat to deploy and run a webapp, but just for static site I don't want to use tomcat server. How do I go about this?

Note: I am trying to deploy my project on heroku.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally got my answer:

Used express js to serve static files

use `npm install express --save -dev`

and then in the `index.js` or `server.js` file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.render('public/');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

So the above line `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` will serve static files like html,css etc from this folder (i.e public)

and then in the command prompt: `node index.js` will start the server

Comment: You don't need a nodejs web-framework to server static files, `http-server` enough

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly  
I am using express js to serve static files

Answer (score -1):

As an addition to [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) anwer

#### To serve static html app

```
npm install -g http-server
http-server ./index.html
```

#### To serve nodejs app

```
npm install -g forever
forever start server.js
```

#### To develop static app

```
//grunt or gulp
//both support watchers, livereaload, minifications, bundling
//google it
```

#### To develop nodejs app

```
express
hapi
meanjs
...many other
```

Comment: As you have mentioned in your last point "To develop nodejs app" to use express and I guess I have already mentioned in my answer using expressjs which can be run locally or when deployed on heroku